# Prevent overriding of already bound classes in guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am trying to re-use a guice module from a Library which has multiple providers, I want to use few providers from the library and provide few in my own module.

Library Module -

```
public class LibraryModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("dbCredentials")
    private AWSCredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider(@Named("app.keySet") String keySet) {
        return new SomeCredentialsProvider(keySet);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private AmazonDynamoDB getDynamoDBClient(@Named("dbCredentials") AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
                                             @Named("aws.region") String region) {

        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                                          .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                                          .withRegion(region)
                                          .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("dbMapper")
    private DynamoDBMapper getDynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient) {

        return new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    }
...... more providers using  dbMapper
```

Now where I want to use this module I want to give some different implementation of `AmazonDynamoDB` which uses the default credential provider.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(AmazonDynamoDB.class).toProvider(AmazonDynamoDBClientProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
        install(new LibraryModule());
    }
```

AmazonDynamoDBClientProvider class -

```
public class AmazonDynamoDBClientProvider implements Provider<AmazonDynamoDB> {

    private final String region;

    @Inject
    public AmazonDynamoDBClientProvider(@Named("aws.region") String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    @Override
    public AmazonDynamoDB get() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                                          .withRegion(region)
                                          .build();
    }
}
```

but when I try to do this it fails in the provider of library while trying to create the AmazonDynamoDB by saying `A binding to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB was already configured`

**I wanted to know if it is possible to omit providers for classes which have already been bound in the parent module?** If yes how do we do that? I was unable to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: How does your application combine the LibraryModule and MyModule?  Via install() ?

Comment: @JanGalinski Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the position to change `LibraryModule`, then you should give it flexibility to bind either its default implementation or the one you're supplying:

```
class LibraryModule extends AbstractModule {

  // Default implementation based on the code you've shown in LibraryModule
  static class DefaultDynamoDBProvider implements Provider<AmazonDynamoDB> {
    private final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    private final String region;

    @Inject DefaultDynamoDBProvider(
        @Named("dbCredentials") AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
        @Named("aws.region") String region) {
      this.credentialsProvider = credentialsProvider;
      this.region = region;
    }
    @Override AmazonDynamoDB get() {
      return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
          .standard()
          .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
          .withRegion(region)
          .build();
    }    
  }

  private Class<Provider<AmazonDynamoDB>> dynamoDbProviderClass;

  // if constructed with this constructor, uses default provider
  LibraryModule() {
    this(DefaultDynamoDBProvider.class);
  }

  // here, uses the supplied one. Builder pattern would be better
  LibraryModule(Class<Provider<AmazonDynamoDB>> providerClass) {
    this.dynamoDbProviderClass = providerClass;
  }

  protected void configure() {
    bind(AmazonDynamoDB.class)
        .toProvider(dynamoDbProviderClass)
        .in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

If however touching `LibraryModule` is impossible, take a look at 
[Overriding Binding in Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483087/overriding-binding-in-guice), while keeping in mind that overriding bindings is an anti-pattern and should be avoided at all costs:

- [Modules.override](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/util/Modules.html) javadoc says "Prefer to write smaller modules that can be reused and tested without overrides," and supplies examples having to do with unit testing
- Guice bindings are hard to track down, but at least there's a promise that once you've found the binding, it's the right one. `Modules.override()` complicate this task further.
- Modules are supposed to be independent of one another. In our scenario, someone may have installed `LibraryModule` and connector to Dynamo just fine, but once he also installed `OrderProcessingModule` (let's assume that's what you're writing), his connection broke. Now he has no recourse: it's either Dynamo or Order Processing, or yet another even-more-complicated override

Comment: Hi @iluxa, can you tell more about why overriding bindings is an anti-pattern and should be avoided at all costs?

Comment: Added a bit of reasoning