# Binding to 2 classes to the same interface

Tags: java, guice

I have an interface interfaceA, classes classA and classB.
classA implements interfaceA, classB implements interfaceA.
classA has business logic and classB is a mocker used for testing purpose.
I want to bind

```
 bind(interfaceA.class).to(classA.class).in(Singleton.class);
 bind(interfaceA.class).to(classB.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

In essence, I always want logic in classA to always be used whenever any method of interface is called and classB to be used for testing the classA implementation.

But when I bind it in the above fashion, I get an error complaining a binding is already defined, can't define binding again for interfaceA. How do I effectively solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding Binding in Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483087/overriding-binding-in-guice)

Answer (score 4):

Don't bind both at once.

In your test configuration, bind the test version and in your production one, bind the real implementation.