# Simplest way to override an endpoint in google guice when writing functional tests

Tags: java, mockito, amazon-dynamodb, guice

I have an application module that installs a DynamoDB module

```
install(new DynamoDBModule());
```

In DynamoDBModule we have some code to build the DynamoDb client and initialize the mapper

```
 AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://prod-endpoint:8000", "us-west-2"))
        .build();
```

Now, when I am writing tests, I have to replace this dynamoDB endpoint with a local endpoint and I was wondering what is the simplest way to do this. I am aware of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483087/6709711), but it would mean writing a lot of code for just a single small change. I would have to create a mock dynamodb module, a mock application module and then I can run something like this in my tests

```
Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new AppModule()).with(new TestAppModule()));
```

Is there a simple way to somehow use or override the test endpoint when running tests and continue using the prod endpoint otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure an `EndpointConfiguration` as binding and override it in `TestAppModule`. E.g.:

```java
class DynamoDBModule {
   @Provides
   @Singleton
   AmazonDynamoDB provideAmazonDynamoDB(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) {
       return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
          .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
          .build()
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   EndpointConfiguration provideEndpointConfiguration() {
       return new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://prod-endpoint:8000", "us-west-2");
   }
}

class TestAppModule {

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   EndpointConfiguration provideTestEndpointConfiguration() {
       return new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("test-value", "us-west-2");
   }
}
```

Then use you approach with `Modules.override` and it should work:

```java
Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new AppModule()).with(new TestAppModule()));
```

Comment: I think this would work. I have another follow up question: what if I have another module let's say, sqs module. Now, I want to override endpoint for both sqs and DynamoDB. How would I do that? Using @Named ? If you could edit your answer and add that it would really help

Comment: I think you have answered my question already @Yurii and that the above should be a different question altogether. I will ask [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70999405/18118996) and accept this as the answer to this.